# Advice on how to refactor a nested try/catch block inside a using clause

Tags: c#

A developer has written the following code below and I am trying to find a better way to refactor it:

```
            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    var proxy = new WebProxy(address, portNo);
                    proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
                    proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                    result = client.DownloadString(httpURL);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("blah blah", ex);

                try
                {
                   SendNotification
                }
                catch (Exception emailEx)
                {
                    log.Error("blahblah " + emailEx);
                }
            }
```

Is the `using` clause required to be inside a `try`/`catch` block, considering it itself is using `try`/`finally`? And then if an exception is thrown inside the `using`, how do I handle it?

Is there a better way to avoid the nested `try`/`catch` when sending a notification?

Comment: Move the `SendNotification` code to its own method.

Comment: 1) Create a method called `public void SendNotificationCatchExceptions()`, 2) Move your nested try/catch into that method. 3) Call `SendNotificationCatchExceptions()` from your main `catch` block.

Comment: you mean call the sendnotification from the parent exception method and then do the try catch within the SendNotification method itself? is that much different from above except it is bit more maintainable?

Comment: It isn't, but I don't see another way that this can go down. You only want to send the notification when an error is caught, and you don't want to error out if the send notification code fails. So the logical conclusion is that the nested try/catch has to exist, whether it's in the code above, or in another method. I'm working under the assumption that `SendNotification` will require the outermost exception, of course.

Comment: Well, does anything keep you from _not_ using `using`? You could refactor into try/catch/finally if the `using` in the `try` is one of the concerns. The "try-in-catch" can only be hidden through a method. If SendNotification can throw, it can throw. If you control it, you could move the try catch inside, but that's all. I'd recommend catching more specific Exceptions, though.

Comment: **And** : _"We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."_ - [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) , so you may also consider switching to newer tech. With HttpClient, though, you wouldn't be using `using` anyway (nor close it manually everytime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `SendNotification` when exception is thrown and handle exceptions in `SendNotification()`:

```
try 
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var proxy = new WebProxy(address, portNo);
        proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;    
        result = client.DownloadString(httpURL);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("blah blah", ex); 
    SendNotification(); 
}
```

And `SendNotification()`:

```
private void SendNotification()
{
    try 
    {
        // Here you are sending notifications
    }
    catch (Exception emailEx)
    {
        log.Error("blahblah " + emailEx);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to avoid nesting is to make it in another function

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("blah blah", ex);
            FUNCTION_NAME()
        }

private RETURN_TYPE  FUNCTION_NAME()
{
         try
        {
           SendNotification
        }
        catch (Exception emailEx)
        {
            log.Error("blahblah " + emailEx);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many C# native libraries use the Try pattern to specify they will not throw:

For example: 
[bool Dictionary.TryAdd(element)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=netcore-3.1)

```
public DoEverything()
{
    if(!TryDownload(..))
    {
        TrySendNotification();
    }
}

public bool TryDownload(out result)
{
    try {
        using(var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var proxy = new WebProxy(address, portNo);
            proxy.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            result = client.DownloadString(httpURL);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("blah blah", ex);  
        return false;
    }
}

public bool TrySendNotification()
{
    try 
    {
        // Here you are sending notifications
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception emailEx)
    {
        log.Error("blahblah " + emailEx);
        return false;
    }    
}
```